Trigger a Lua script when pressing a modifier on a keyboard in Logitech G Hub
I want to create simple lua script in Logitech G Hub for quick looking behind in the game.
I manage to make it work using mouse button to trigger it:
--Script -> MMB - look back

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 
   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
  
     PressKey("lctrl")

        for i = 0, 96 do
        
         MoveMouseRelative (-25,0) 
         Sleep (1)
            
        end
  
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 3) then

      ReleaseKey("lctrl")

    end

end


So when I'm pressing middle mouse button, script automatically is pressing lctrl modifier (free look in game), the mouse movement is initiated to move camera in game and after releasing mouse button, lctrl is also released what results in quitting from free look.
However, I would like to change triggering of that script to use for it only modifier lctrl without pressing mmiddle mouse button.
I'm trying different configurations with IsModifierPressed("lshift") but nothing gave successful results so far. I'd be grateful for any guidance. I'm taking my first steps with lua scripts so childish explanations are welcome ;)
